# Alternative python codes to get a floating point number from the user and check if the integer part is even or odd

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a python program to get a floating-point number from the user and check if the integer part is even or odd.I could do the task with two methods, one by using function and the other with nested ifs:

```
a = float(input('Enter a floating point number: '))
def integer_part(m):
    if m - round(m) >= 0:
        return round(m)
    else:
        return round(m) - 1
if integer_part(a) % 2 == 0:
    print('Even')
else:
    print('Odd')
```

```
a = float(input('Enter a number please: '))
if a - round(a) >= 0:
    if round(a) % 2 == 0:
        print('Even')
    else:
        print('Odd')
else:
    if round(a) % 2 == 0:
        print('Odd')
    else:
        print('Even')
```

Since, I'm new to python I would be glad to see alternative codes that do this task.

Comment: @rochard4u As I mentioned in the last line of the post, I'm looking for alternative codes.

Comment: @Etemon Open-ended review & suggestion questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you'd like a review of your working code, you could try posting on [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to check with their content guidelines before asking.

Comment: `print("Even" if int(a) % 2 == 0 else "Odd")`

Comment: Just convert to integer directly.  `a = int(float(input(...)))`.  Why are you bothering to round?  You didn't say rounding was required.

Comment: @JohnGordon No it's not required. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the follow code

```
a = float(input('Enter a floating point number: '))

    if a // 1 % 2 == 0:
        print('Even')
    else:
        print('Odd')
```

besides, i do not know why you use round.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to remove the part after the decimal point and then check if the integer part is even or odd.

```
number = float(input("Enter a floating-point number: "))
integer_part = int(str(number).split(".")[0])
    
if integer_part % 2 == 0:
    print(f"The integer part {integer_part} is even.")
else:
    print(f"The integer part {integer_part} is odd.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```py
if int(float(input("Enter a floating point number: "))) % 2 == 0:
    print("Even")
else:
    print("Odd")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many, but here is a one-liner:

`print("ODD") if int(float(input("Enter a floating point number: "))) % 2 else print("EVEN")`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = float(input('Enter a floating point number: '))

if (a - round(a)) % 2 == 0: print('Even') 
else: print('Odd')
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).